# Determining the Cardinality of a Setwise Stabiliser

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-groups

If I were to have $A$ be a finite set with order $n$ and $X\subset A$, and then define $G_X$ by:

$G_X=\{g \in$ Sym $(A) \; \vert\; g(X) = X\}$

How would I go about finding the $\vert G_X \vert$? The only thing I can think to start with is that $\vert$Sym($A)\vert$ = $n!$ But other than that, I am quite unsure.

I have already proved that $G_X \leq$ Sym($A$).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is really combinatorics rather than group theory. How many permutations permute the sets $X$ and $A \setminus X$? It's not very difficult.

Comment: Edited. Sorry @DerekHolt I am not really following. Is it $\vert X \vert !$ and $(n-\vert X \vert)!$

Comment: Yes, and the answer is the product of those two numbers.